# Cannot populate record to bootstrap modal when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please I need some help, I have been working so hard to populate a record to bootstrap modal when a link is clicked so that user can edit and update the record. The link is not in form, its in a table.
Below are my nonworking codes:

**The HTML**

```
<div class="widget-content">
                        <form action="#" method="GET">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable datatable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                             <th class="checkbox-column">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="uniform">
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Full Name</th>
                                        <th>Company Name</th>
                                        <th>Business Location</th>
                                        <th>Telephone</th>
                                        <th>Credit Limit</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                    $query="select * from customer_vendor";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ){
                    $firstname = $row['first_name'];
                    $lastname = $row['last_name'];
                    $fullname = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
                    $climit = number_format($row['credit_limit'],2);
                 echo
                            "<tr>
                                <td class=\"checkbox-column\">
                                            <input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"uniform\" >
                                            <input type=\"hidden\"  >
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <ul class=\"table-controls\">
                                                <li><a   class=\"bs-tooltip\" id=\"updateit\" name=\"update_cv\" data-class=\"{$row['customer_vendor_id']}\" data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#update_customer_vendor\"  title=\"Edit\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i></a> </li>
                                                <li><a class=\"bs-tooltip\" data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#delete_customer_vendor\" title=\"Delete\"><i class=\"icon-trash\"></i></a> </li>
                                </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td>{$row['customer_vendor_id']}</td>
                                <td>$fullname</td>
                                <td>{$row['company_name']}</td>
                                <td>{$row['business_location']}</td>
                                <td>{$row['telephone']}</td>
                                <td>$climit</td>                            
                            </tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </form>
                            <a href="create_new_cust_vend.php"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"> New</i></button></a>
                        </div>
```

**The modal:**

```
<div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="update_customer_vendor">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Updating customer - Vendor</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body" id="update_modal">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="fa fa-save"> Update</i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

**The script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#updateit").click(function(){
            var studentClass =$("#updateit").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"update_cust_vend.php",
                data:"updateit="+studentClass,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#update_modal").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's with all the slashes in your attributes for your link tag?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? Do you not see the value when you are trying to assign it to studentClass? I have seen some issues with modal windows where they are rendered outside of the DOM. so the jquery selector won't see it. Have you tried to use firebug or chrome dev tools to set breakpoints on the JS to see what the actual values are or if you can even see it in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following. i think that should fix it.

```
<li><a   class=\"bs-tooltip\" id=\"updateit\" name=\"update_cv\" data-class="studentclass" data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#update_customer_vendor\"  title=\"Edit\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i></a> </li>
```

link must contain studentClass somewhere it's not a input field so can't use val() .
i.e  data-class="studentclass" in above link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#updateit").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var studentClass =$(this).data('class'); // get studentclass form link.
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"update_cust_vend.php",
            data:"updateit="+studentClass,
            success:function(data){
                $("#update_modal").html(data);
                $("#update_customer_vendor").modal();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i cant't test your code directly. so just did demo in jsfiddle . example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrva27h6/)

Comment: Now i can see the value passed to the data-class at the console when i run it, but the problem now is how to pass that value to the update_cust_vend.php

Comment: you have already passed updateit value in this line
 "data:"updateit="+studentClass," 
.. now you just need to get that value in php i.e. $class = $_GET['updateit']; then do your task and print result i.e. echo $result.

Comment: Now it can echo to modal but it only picks the first ID in the table. The rest does not echo

Comment: remove id=\"updateit\" and add that id to class i.e. class=\"bs-tooltip updateit\" . 

then replace $("#updateit") with $(".updateit")

Comment: how do I load the "waiting dialog" before loading the modal?

Comment: i.e. [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/wafibimobi/1/) and [JSBin code](http://jsbin.com/wafibimobi/1/edit). i've removed data in ajax just to avoid 404 error. you don't need to remove data.. just add additional codes i've added. and also remove data-toogle="modal" from link "edit".

Comment: the loading works but but the ID is not picking  to display records

Comment: Its working now. Just updated code with the new one sent. Thanks

Comment: I use paginated table, and it does not work for the records at the " Next" page. It only works for five records. Any help?

Comment: replace   "
$("#updateit").on('click', function(e){" with $(document).on('click', '#updateit', function(e){

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the following to your click event to prevent the default behaviour of the hyperlink:

```
$("#updateit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

After that I am confused, you are taking the value of your hyperlink here:

```
var studentClass =$("#updateit").val();
```

Is this not a mistake? Because your hyperlink doesn't have a value...

You can store a value in a custom made attribute. To do so you must define your attribute with the `data-` prefix. So for example `data-value`.

So your hyper link would be:

```
<li><a class=\"bs-tooltip\" id=\"updateit\" ... data-value="1"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i></a></li>
```

To get the value use:

```
var studentClass = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

Where `$(this)` refers to your clicked hyperlink.

And in your success handler after populating the html you don't show the modal, add this:

```
$('#update_customer_vendor').modal('show');
```

Comment: What kind of value do you want in your `studentClass`, is it an Id of someting or...?

Comment: yea its an ID from the DB

Comment: if you update your code like I presented above, can you check if your `update_cust_vend.php` gets this id?

Comment: It does not get the ID when I echo it out

Comment: And if you echo static test, does that work? in order to see if the ajax call itself is working

Comment: I have post the full code, so please review and help

Comment: change your data in your ajax call to `data: { updateit: studentClass }`. Can you update the question with the changes I mentioned and which you have applied to your project in order to get a correct view of the code you have at the moment

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#updateit").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var studentClass =$(this).data('class'); // get studentclass form link.
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"update_cust_vend.php",
            data: { updateit: studentClass }
            success:function(data){
                $("#update_modal").html(data);
                $("#update_customer_vendor").modal();
            }
        });
    });
});